# TestNG @AfterMethod with DataProvider

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

I was playing around with TestNG and found that @AfterMethod & @BeforeMethod is getting invoked more than once when I'm using dataProvider. Is it possible to invoke a method only once after the @Test got executed with all the parameters passed from dataProvider. Like can we invoke 'tearDown' method only once after 'testPrimeNumberChecker' got called for 5 times by dataProvider.

```
import org.testng.Assert;    
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;    
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    

public class ParamTestWithDataProvider1 {    
    private PrimeNumberChecker primeNumberChecker;    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ParamTestWithDataProvider1.class);    

    @BeforeMethod    
    public void initialize() {    
        logger.info("Before Method Fired !! - " );    
        primeNumberChecker = new PrimeNumberChecker();    
    }    

    @@AfterMethod    
    public void tearDown() {    
        logger.info("After Method Fired !!  " );      
    }    

    @DataProvider(name = "test1")    
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {    
        return new Object[][] { { 2, true }, { 6, false }, { 19, true },    
            { 22, false }, { 23, true } };    
    }    

    @Test(dataProvider = "test1")    
    public void testPrimeNumberChecker(Integer inputNumber,    
        Boolean expectedResult) {    
    logger.info(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);    
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult,    
            primeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be to use @BeforeGroups and @AfterGroups.  Make your test fall in a group and then use the Before/After groups annotation to do setup/teardown once for the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I want propose you a lazy idea: 
You can use a TestListener extended class and put tearDown method into a specific method of this class (i.e. tearDownListener).
In onTestFailure and onTestSuccess you can increment a counter.
When TestListener intercept last test you can execute tearDownListener.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to use `ITestNGMethod#hasMoreInvocation` to check whether it is the last method invocation.

```java
    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult testResult) {
        if (!testResult.getMethod().hasMoreInvocation()) {
            // This will be executed once, after a test method has been invoked for all parameters sequences defined in the corresponding @DataProvider
        }
    }
```

Please make sure to add `alwaysRun = true` if you want the method to be executed even in case of failure.